# Strange behaviour of GestureEvent.rotation on iOS webkit

Tags: javascript, ios, html, touch, mobile-website

I am using javascript Gesture events to detect multitouch pan/scale/rotation applied to an element in a HTML document.

Visit this URL with an iPad:
http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/rotate_test/

You can touch the element with two finger and rotate it, but sometimes the rotation property goes go astray and my element flips around many full rotations.

Here is part of my code, I am really only taking the value directly from the event object:

```
...bind("gesturechange",function(e){        
       e.preventDefault();      
       curX = e.originalEvent.pageX - startX;
       curY = e.originalEvent.pageY - startY;
       node.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (e.originalEvent.rotation) + "deg)" +
                     " scale(" + e.originalEvent.scale + ") translate3D(" + curX + "px, " + curY + "px, 0px)";              
}...
```

What happens is that the value gets either 360 degrees added or subtracted, so I could monitor the value and react to sudden large changes, but this feels like a last resort.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

In order to avoid sudden changes in the rotation that don't reflect real finger moves you need to test for that. I do that testing if the rotation changed more then 300 degrees in either direction, if it does then you need to add or subtract 360 depending on the direction. Not really intuitive, but it works.

Fixed page is here:
http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/rotate_test/index2.html

Here is the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var node;
        var node_rotation=0;
        var node_last_rotation=0;

        $('.frame').bind("gesturestart",function(e){    
            e.preventDefault();
            node=e.currentTarget;       
            startX=e.originalEvent.pageX;
            startY=e.originalEvent.pageY;
            node_rotation=e.originalEvent.rotation;
            node_last_rotation=node_rotation;

        }).bind("gesturechange",function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            //whats the difference to the last given rotation?
            var diff=(e.originalEvent.rotation-node_last_rotation)%360;
            //test for the outliers and correct if needed
            if( diff<-300)
            {
                diff+=360;
            }
            else if(diff>300)
            {
                diff-=360;
            }   
            node_rotation+=diff;
            node_last_rotation=e.originalEvent.rotation;     

            node.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (node_rotation) + "deg)" +
                " scale(" + (e.originalEvent.scale) + 
                ") translate3D(" + (e.originalEvent.pageX - startX) + "px, " + (e.originalEvent.pageY - startY) + "px, 0px)";   

        }).bind("gestureend",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                  
        });
    </script>
```